# Not able to ask questions : what to do

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

What should I do now ? I did all the things that were mentioned here -> http://goo.gl/C1Kwu

I removed my poor questions, tried helping people by answering whenever I can.

I want to ask questions like a normal user and get my problems solved !

So I request SO community for giving me my right back for asking questions.

(P.S. Please add tags to the question, I do not know what to tag.)

Comment: Why did you remove your poor questions? Were you not able to edit them into good questions? And just a hint: we can't unban you. Nobody can. Only you can unban yourself through positive actions which might result in the ban being automatically lifted. This is not a manual process.

Comment: why did you short-link internal content? You can use link syntax `[Yahoo](http://www.yahoo.com)`

Comment: @Xaade: This is, inexplicably, how it's displayed to the recipient of the message.

Comment: @Xaade Valet is right

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11728548/99456) of yours:

> Actually I was being stupid !!Lol, but yes... we can easily have .class file of any java file put into war. That was the real question and not use of Ant actually... it can be done by going to java build path and putting the path there where you want to put .class files in the source section. So I guess it maybe useful to someone in future, knowing where to put .class files :)

Please rephrase it to read like an actual answer and not like a casual text message.

Other than that you seem to have a tendency to answer your own questions. That's fine, in general, however it seems to me that you are trying to cheat by asking trivial questions and answering them immediately. That's *not* going to help you lift the question ban, come on, the whole point is to help *other* people, and nothing in what you are doing is particularly helpful to others. Some examples of your self answers:

- [Adding Script to ASPX page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054149/adding-script-to-aspx-page)
- [Goodreads Api : Book review parsing : Iframe in the XML : How to remove that Iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955217/goodreads-api-book-review-parsing-iframe-in-the-xml-how-to-remove-that-ifr)
- [GWT, GWT Designer and Eclipse Plugin Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234066/gwt-gwt-designer-and-eclipse-plugin-issue)
- [Putting .class files in war folder by someway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314171/putting-class-files-in-war-folder-by-someway)
- [Eclipse 3.7 Indigo-'Install new software' not progressing : GWT Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232486/eclipse-3-7-indigo-install-new-software-not-progressing-gwt-designer)

In a couple of those you received better answers than your own, but you went ahead and accepted your answers.

Comment: OK I will do that now...I have changed the content there...

Comment: Yannis, there is really no intention of cheat from my side !! Few of the questions where not trivial, believe me. I was really having tough time. But I solved them by my own, so it is rather thanks to my research and efforts.

Comment: @AnujKulkarni That's ok then, but it won't help lift your question ban. Try giving some _good_ answers to other people's questions.

Comment: Believe me SO is my last option for solving a problem, I research alot and then only put question on SO. And if I manage to solve the issue, then why not post a solution that worked for me? it will help others if they are in same boat. I dont know what else I can do to clarify me ?

Comment: I am giving answers to questions that I can, and building the reputations, but I do not know when my question ban will be revoked?

Comment: @AnujKulkarni The question ban process is automatic, no one can help you with it, or give you more information about it. Keep improving your posts and providing good answers, and the ban will be lifted at some point. As I pointed to you in my answer there was at least one answer of yours that was in urgent need of improvement, so you do have at least some work left. Do it, and the ban will go away eventually.

Comment: @AnujKulkarni It's a good idea if you're going to answer your own question to provide more content than others would. In other words, a comprehensive answer detailing why you were wrong, how to avoid the mistake, and your path to finding a solution. At least then, even if your question is trivial, we're building a repository of teachable moments.

Comment: @Yanniz : Yes, thanks :) I will keep going and lets see, when will I be able to ask questions again.. thanks for your help regarding answers.

Comment: @Xaade I will keep that in mind ! I try to document as such as I can ...